# How to get Streams of File Attributes from the FileSystem?

Tags: java, scala, performance, java-stream, akka

I am writing a Web Server and am trying to make sure I am as efficient as possible, minimizing File System Calls. The problem is that the methods that return Streams such as [java.nio.file.Files.list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list) return a Stream of `Paths`, and I would like to have a Stream of [BasicFileAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html), so that I can return the creation time and update time for each Path (on say returning results for an [LDP Container](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/#ldpc-container)).

Of course a simple solution would be to `map` each element of the Stream with a function that takes the path and returns a file attribute `(p: Path) => Files.getAttributeView...`  but that sounds like it would make a call to the FS for each Path, which seems like a waste, because to get the file information the JDK can't have been far from the Attribute info.

I actually came across this mail from [2009 OpenJDK mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nio-dev/2009-September/000657.html) that states that they had discussed adding an API that would return a pair of a Path and Attributes...

I found a non-public class on the JDK `java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker` which has an api that would allow one to fetch the attributes `FileTreeWalker.Event`. That actually makes use of a `sun.nio.fs.BasicFileAttributesHolder` which allows a Path to keep a cache of the Attributes. But it's not public and it is not clear where it works.

There is of course also the whole [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) API, and that has methods that return both a `Path` and `BasicFileAttributes` as shown here:

```
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attr) {...}
```

So I am looking if there is a way to turn that into a Stream which respects the principle of back pressure from the [Reactive Manifesto](https://www.reactivemanifesto.org) that was pushed by [Akka](https://akka.io/), without it hogging too many resources. I checked the open source [Alpakka File](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/file.html) project, but that is also streaming the `Files` methods that return `Path`s ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access file attributes with their path by using `Files.find` which accepts a BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> and store the value as it tests each path.

The side effect action inside the BiPredicate will enable operations on both objects without needing to touch the file system per item in the path. With your predicate condition `yourPred`, side effect `predicate` below will collect the attributes for you to retrieve inside the stream processing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path dir = Path.of(args[0]);

    // Use `ConcurrentHashMap` if using `stream.parallel()`
    HashMap <Path,BasicFileAttributes> attrs = new HashMap<>();

    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> yourPred = (p,a) -> true;

    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> {
        return yourPred.test(p, a)
                // && p.getNameCount() == dir.getNameCount()+1 // Simulates Files.list
                && attrs.put(p, a) == null;
    };
    try(var stream = Files.find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, predicate)) {
        stream.forEach(p-> System.out.println(p.toString()+" => "+attrs.get(p)));
        // Or: if your put all your handling code in the predicate use stream.count();
    }
}
```

To similate the effect of `File.list` use a one level `find` scanner:

```
 BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> yourPred = (p,a) -> p.getNameCount() == dir.getNameCount()+1;
```

For a large folder scan you should clean up the attrs map as you go by inserting `attrs.remove(p);` after consuming the path.

**Edit**

The answer above can be refactored to a 3 line call returning stream of `Map.Entry<Path, BasicFileAttributes>`, or it's easy to add a class/record to hold the Path/BasicFileAttribute pair and return `Stream<PathInfo>` instead:

```
/**
 * Call Files.find() returning a stream with both Path+BasicFileAttributes
 * as type Map.Entry<Path, BasicFileAttributes>
 * <p>Could declare a specific record to replace Map.Entry as:
 *    record PathInfo(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attr) { };
 */
public static Stream<Map.Entry<Path, BasicFileAttributes>>
find(Path dir, int maxDepth, BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> matcher, FileVisitOption... options) throws IOException {

    HashMap <Path,BasicFileAttributes> attrs = new HashMap<>();
    BiPredicate<Path, BasicFileAttributes> predicate = (p,a) -> (matcher == null || matcher.test(p, a)) && attrs.put(p, a) == null;

    return Files.find(dir, maxDepth, predicate, options).map(p -> Map.entry(p, attrs.remove(p)));
}
```

Comment: Great idea! 
As I am mostly coding Scala, I did not grok the implications of the bipredicate function, and somehow got stuck on those other methods. This looks like combined with Akka (or Java) streams should give the perfect answer. I'll investigate... Thanks for redirecting my search :-)

Answer (score 2):

If there's some way of directly getting those attributes, I don't know.

On converting the FileVisitor API to reactive streams:

The mechanism of reactive streams backpressure is a pull-push model, where a demand is first signaled by downstream (the pull part) and then the upstream is allowed to send no more items than the demand signaled (the push part).

The problem with the FileVisitor API is that there's no way to directly hookup with such control flow mechanism. Once you set it off it just goes calling your callback and not caring too much about anything else.

There's no clean way of bridging this, but one way you could do that is using the `Source.queue` (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html) to isolate that API from the rest of your stream like that:

```scala
val queue = 
Source.queue[BasiFileAttributes](bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      //the rest of your Akka Streams pipeline
      .run(system);
```

This will materialize to queue that you can now pass to your `FileVisitor`. Anything you `offer` to that queue will go down the stream. If when you `offer` there's no demand and the queue is full the `Future` returned by `offer` will not complete until such time that there's space in the queue. So in the API you could simply do:

```
//inside the FileVisitor API callback
Await.result(queue.offer(attrs), Duration.Inf)
```

And that would block the callback thread when the stream is backpressured. Ugly but isolated.

Comment: Can just block in the callback ... back pressure.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your comment. The reactive streams backpressure is non blocking, so blocking is just against reactive streams spec. Sometimes you just have no choice when youre dealing with an API like the FileVisitor` I employed similar strategy when dealing with similarily behaving API of Amazon KCL library. The idea is to isolate the blocking part from the rest of the stream that can operate in fully non blocking manner.

Comment: I think the answer by DuncG above combined with Akka should give an answer that is not ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from DuncG's answer I got the following to work in Scala3 as a pretty generic Akka Stream class. This is actually very neat as it creates a sideffect of the `Files.find` function which it immediately encapsulates back into a clean functional reactive stream.

```
class DirectoryList(
    dir: Path, 
    matcher: (Path, BasicFileAttributes) => Boolean = (p,a) => true, 
    maxDepth: Int = 1
) extends GraphStage[SourceShape[(Path,BasicFileAttributes)]]:
    import scala.jdk.FunctionConverters.*
    import scala.jdk.OptionConverters.*
    
    val out: Outlet[(Path,BasicFileAttributes)] = Outlet("PathAttributeSource")
    override val shape = SourceShape(out)


    override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic =
        new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
            private var next: (Path,BasicFileAttributes) = _

            def append(path: Path, att: BasicFileAttributes): Boolean = 
                val matched = matcher(path,att)
                if matched then next = (path,att)
                matched
            
            private val pathStream = Files.find(dir, maxDepth, append.asJava)
            private val sit = pathStream.iterator()
            
            setHandler(out, new OutHandler {
                override def onPull(): Unit = { 
                    if sit.hasNext then
                        sit.next()
                        push(out,next)
                    else
                        pathStream.close()  
                        complete(out)
                }

                override def onDownstreamFinish(cause: Throwable): Unit =
                    pathStream.close()  
                    super.onDownstreamFinish(cause)
            })
        }
end DirectoryList
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
val sourceGraph = DirectoryList(Path.of("."),depth=10)
val result = Source.fromGraph(sourceGraph).map{ (p: Path,att: BasicFileAttributes) => 
        println(s"received <$p> : dir=${att.isDirectory}")}.run()
```

The full source code [is here on github](https://github.com/co-operating-systems/Reactive-SoLiD/blob/master/src/main/scala/run/cosy/ldp/fs/DirectoryList.scala) and an initial test [here](https://github.com/co-operating-systems/Reactive-SoLiD/blob/master/src/test/scala/run/cosy/ldp/fs/DirectoryListSpec.scala).
Perhaps one could improve it by tuning the answers so that a certain number of path attribute pairs are passed along in bulk.

Comment: I proposed this to the Alpakka group https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/2621